# Angular Reactive Form Validation Complete Event

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have a reactive form which having around 10 fields with 2 async validations each and in that, I have to design autosave feature like when a user navigates from a website and come back later he will get the same state of the form where he left. when autosave data render on UI it again validates all fields.

Is there any way to detect when all form validations complete?

Comment: is there any specific thing you want to do after all the validations are done? maybe there's another way.

Comment: I want to show loader until all validations done

Comment: Do you use Angulars `Formbuilder`?

Comment: @sHamann yes i am using formbuider

Comment: maybe use loader in the validator function?

Comment: `Formbuilder` has an inbuild function `heroForm.invalid` which is an simple bool.

Comment: https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#statusChanges

Comment: An example of asyncValidator  in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56723416/showing-error-after-form-submit-in-angular-reactive-form/56728046?noredirect=1#comment100042119_56728046

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick

```
this.form.statusChange(
   filter(status=>status==='VALID'),
   switchMap(_=>this.yourAutoSaveFunction(this.form.value))
).subscribe()
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can active that using angular forms**

[reactive-forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

```
profileForm = this.fb.group({
    firstName: ['', Validators.required],
    lastName: [''],
    address: this.fb.group({
      street: [''],
      city: [''],
      state: [''],
      zip: ['']
    }),
    aliases: this.fb.array([
      this.fb.control('')
    ])
  });
```

**then on submit** 
you can get all values

```
onSubmit() {
    // TODO: Use EventEmitter with form value
    console.log(this.profileForm.value);
  }
```

then you can save Localstorage it

[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

The following snippet accesses the current domain's local Storage object and adds a data item to it using Storage.setItem().

```
localStorage.setItem('formdata', this.profileForm.value);
```

The syntax for reading the localStorage item is as follows:

```
var cat = localStorage.getItem('formdata');
```

**

> UPDATED

**

If you want to get only the status and not the value you can use statusChanges:

```
export class Component {

    @ViewChild('myForm') myForm;

    this.myForm.statusChanges.subscribe(
        result => console.log(result)
    );
}
```

If you even want data changes, you can subscribe to the valueChanges of the form and check the status of the form using this.myForm.status:

```
export class Component {

    @ViewChild('myForm') myForm;

    this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(
        result => console.log(this.myForm.status)
    );
}
```

Possible values of status are: **VALID**, **INVALID**, **PENDING**, or **DISABLED**.

Comment: but I want to show loader until set form data validation is complete.

Comment: thanks @orbit, I will implement this and mark as correct answer if it works.