# Server validation for mat-input

Tags: angular, angular-material

I made server validation for my angular-material form.

And I have two problems, first is, I need to set my `<mat-error></mat-error>` where I show my message from server response,  outside from `<mat-form-fiel>`

```
 <mat-form-field>
   <input formControlName="lastName"
    matInput
    placeholder="Last Name*"
    (focusout)="lastNameError = null"
    />
    <mat-error>This field is required</mat-error>  //--> this one is standard mat validation, and working on this place
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-error class="mat-error-custom">{{ lastNameError }}</mat-error>  //--> this one is for showing my server message, and this one need to stay outside from mat-form-fiel to work
```

Is there way to set this inside?

**And second question**

How to set error class for the input field if I use my server-side validation?
Now I have something like this

[image]

But I want to set the class to get this red borders like material set if we use material validators
[image]

Here is a method where I get and set all my server response msgs

```
    this.errorsMsgs$.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe((error: any) => {
      this.resetErrorMesg();
      if (error) {
        for (let err of error.errors) {
          if (err.field === "lastName") {
            this.lastNameError = err.defaultMessage;
            this.addNewUserForm.get("lastName").setErrors({ valid: false }); //--> I try add this but not working
          }
          if (err.field === "firstName") {
            this.firstNameError = err.defaultMessage;
          }
          if (err.field === "email") {
            this.emailError = err.defaultMessage;
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: Try: `this.addNewUserForm.get("lastName").setErrors({ 'valid': false });`? or `setErrors({'incorrect': true});`? or `this.addNewUserForm.get("lastName").markAsTouched();`?

Comment: if I try to add `'valid'` my tslint automatically on save removes quotes

Comment: also, I try this `.markAsTouched()` but same problem :/

Comment: You can use mat-error with async validators as usual mat-error. I suggest only in a submit but, anyway, you has a example in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56723416/showing-error-after-form-submit-in-angular-reactive-form/56728046#56728046

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I fix this in this way...
I loop thru the errors from `ngrx@store` and set errors to formControl

```
this.errorsMsgs$ = this.store.select(fromStore.UserSelectors.getErrors);
    this.errorsMsgs$.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe((error: any) => {
      if (error) {
        for (let err of error.errors) {
          const formControl = this.addNewUserForm.get(err.field);
          if (formControl) {
            formControl.setErrors({
              serverError: err.defaultMessage
            });
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

And in HTML I check for errors and show them near input field

```
<mat-form-field>
        <input
          formControlName="firstName"
          matInput
          placeholder="First Name*"
        />
        <mat-error *ngIf="addNewUserForm.get('firstName').errors?.minlength">
          Min length is 5 character
        </mat-error>
        <mat-error *ngIf="addNewUserForm.get('firstName').errors?.maxlength">
          Max length is 16 characters
        </mat-error>
        <mat-error *ngIf="addNewUserForm.get('firstName').errors?.serverError">
          {{ addNewUserForm.get("firstName").errors?.serverError }}  // --> here is from server response error
        </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
```

Also, if you submit your form thru the ngrx@effect like I, then in submit add

```
this.yourForm.markAllAsTouched();
```

Without this, when you submit your form and get error response, you need to `touch` every input to show msg, on this way you automatically touch all field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `asyncValidatorFunction` like in my example. You can change the http method or anithing you want. [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uprutj?file=src%2Fmain.ts). In my example the input validation called every 'blur' (native input onblur) but you can change this to 'change', or 'submit'.