# angular form reactive driven form in anular

Tags: angular

I want to a validation to submit unique data  by using reactive model form that means when user enter duplicate data that is already present in table then submit button should be disabled How to resolve it
?

please anyone help me as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

firstly import the import `FormBuilder, FormGroup,Validators` like that

```js
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
```

in your component
and then

```js
export class YourComponent {
  dataForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private dataValidationService: DataValidationService
  ) {
    this.dataForm = this.fb.group({
      data: ['', [Validators.required]],
    });
  }
  async checkDataUniqueness() {
    const data = this.dataForm.get('data').value;
    const isUnique = await this.dataValidationService.checkUniqueness(data).toPromise();

    if (isUnique) {
      this.dataForm.get('data').setErrors(null);
    } else {
      this.dataForm.get('data').setErrors({ notUnique: true });
    }
  }

  submitForm() {
    if (this.dataForm.valid) {
    }
  }
}
```

add in the `HTML` as well

```html
<form [formGroup]="dataForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
  <inputtype="text" formControlName="data"(input)="checkDataUniqueness()"/>
  <div *ngIf="dataForm.get('data').hasError('notUnique')">
    This data is not unique.
  </div>
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!dataForm.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: checkUniqueness it thrown an error

Comment: In Reactive Forms you has async validators, see, e.g. this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56723416/showing-error-after-form-submit-in-angular-reactive-form/56728046#56728046)

Comment: Hi  @Abdur  i this it is because the angular version